# Text Data binding doesn't work in Retrofit2 callback

Tags: android, data-binding, android-mvvm

I am tying to show username after signing in succeeded.

```
    private fun getInfo(context: Context, userkey: String){
        binding!!.initVm!!.username = "Hello, boo1"

        ServiceGenerator
                .createService(Service::class.java)!!
                .getUserInfo(userkey)
                .enqueue(object : Callback<UserInfo> {
                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<UserInfo>, t: Throwable) {
                        binding!!.initVm!!.username = "Hello, boo5"
                    }

                    override fun onResponse(call: Call<UserInfo>, response: Response<UserInfo>) {
                        val result = response.body()!!
                        if (response.isSuccessful){
                            Log.d("test", "Hello, ${response.body()!!.username}")
                            binding!!.initVm!!.username = "Hello, boo2"
                        }else{
                            binding!!.initVm!!.username = "Hello, boo3"
                        }
                    }
                })
    }
```

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_greeting"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="@{initVm.username}"
        android:visibility="@{initVm.greetingVisibility}"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

Even if the network communication was successful, It doesn't bind data. So, it shows 'Hello, boo1'. That's weird. Does it happen because Asyc? How can I solve this problem?

I can insert the text by accessing View. But I do not want to do that and I'd like to use binding.

```
class  InitViewModel(handler: InitHandler) : ViewModel() {
    var handler = handler
    var greetingVisibility = View.VISIBLE
    var logInVisibility = View.VISIBLE
    var username = "Hello, N/A"
    // ... methods
}
```

Comment: What is this initVm

Comment: @AbrahamMathew updated. I think it doesn't matter because `Hello, boo1` worked fine.

Comment: you are calling getInfo() and your value got updated to Hello, boo1,but youa re not hitting success or failure.If it was success then it would have changed

Comment: Also this approach is not good.You can set your details that you are getting from api inside viewmodel livedata variable and can easily show it inside fragment/activity

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's because of Async. It's rather because you **username** is not observable, so its changes doesn't affect on your UI.

To update UI with binding your **username var** in ViewModel should be observable - either LiveData (in that case it is not necessary to observe it explicitly - DataBinding framework will do it for you) or [ObservableField String](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability#observable_fields)

If you choose LiveData you should set new value from inside your Fragment|Activity with just:

```
binding!!.initVm!!.username.value = "Hello, boo2"
```

And after that UI will be updated

Comment: Then, can you explain why `Hello, boo1` works? And I don't use LiveData.

Comment: I guess you call getInfo just after your binding var was initialised? Just for test - try to delay this "Hello, boo1" setting with handler (one second would be enough) and check whether result will be the same.

Comment: I mean what time is between "binding.initVm = yourViewModel" and "getInfo" invoking? The second follows the first or it starts before?

Comment: I initialize `binding` in `onCreateView()` and I call `getInfo()` in `onResume()`. So, It doesn't matter. And also, `Hello, boo1` is set already(username itself has `Hello, N/A` before it is set) without any problem. So, It doesn't make sense. It should work afterwards.

Comment: Well, I gave you two ways for experiments: 1. Use ObservableField<String> as a type of userName (if you are against LiveData). 2. Use Handler to delay your setting userName with 1 second. Can you try them? First should solve problem, second - to explain (somehow) your use-case. If both experiments fails, other guys could exclude this scenario to advice you something more reliable.